# possible to run nextjs 14(!) and capacitorjs

Tags: next.js, capacitor, next.js14

Is it possible to use nextjs 13 or 14 together with capacitorjs?
The latest two versions 13 or 14 or nextjs work with server components underlaying. For capacitor to work you have to statically export all files. However, using server components there is no need to do ajax calls anymore. Therefore I am not quite sure if the backend is responding to a webwrapped app.
I can handly find anything related to these new versions of nextjs together with capacitorjs.
Does anyone already have insights?